# Using Toggle Statements in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas, toggle

I am attempting to create a program that toggles certain sections of the code on or off based on user input. The code below should only run when the prog1 variable is set equal to Y. However, my log is showing that the code runs no matter what. Does anyone know what is going on?

Code:

```
%let prog1 = Y;
%let prog2 = N;

data _null_;
if "&prog1." = "Y" then do;
    %findit(&file1.);
    %findit(&file2);
end;
run;

data _null_;
if "prog2." = "Y" then do;
    %findit(&file3.);
end;
run;
```

Log:

[image: Log file showing that the macro runs even when the prog variable is set to N]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing what you told it to do.  The macro references and macro code will be evaluated first. Then any SAS code that the macro references generate will by processed by SAS.  So you have written a DATA step that will conditionally skip over the SAS code that the macros generate.  But the macros themselves will always run.

If you code the main program as a macro instead of open SAS code then you can add macro logic like `%IF` to conditionally generate the macro calls.

Or for this simple example you could use `CALL EXECUTE()` or other code generation methods to control the generation of the macro calls.  That way SAS will never see the macro calls in the input stream if the condition is false.

```
data _null_;
  if "&prog1." = "Y" then do;
    call execute('%nrstr(%findit)(&file1.)');
    call execute('%nrstr(%findit)(&file2.)');
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistake in your code. (use of macro function into a dataset, misuse of & (ampercent) in the call of your macro-variable).

1) Always use the & (ampercent) to call a macro-variable
2) Add a point like &path. when it's necessary, if there is another string or macro-variable following the &path macro-variable.
3) Prefer to make your check using macro function with %if,%then, ect.

You should make your program more macro oriented like that :

```
%let prog1 = Y;
%let prog2 = Y;

%macro check();

%if "&prog1." = "Y" %then %do;
    %put execute 1;
    %findit(&file1);
    %findit(&file2);
%end;

%if "&prog2." = "Y" %then %do;
    %put execute 2;
    %findit(&file3);
%end;

%mend;

%check;
```

It will work now,

Regards,

Comment: I tried this and I got an error saying that the %if statement is not valid in open code. Are you saying to create another macro and run that?

Comment: Yes, in the solution here, you have to create a new macro function named %check. Otherwise you will not be able to use %if,%then.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement is checking "prog2." not "&prog2." and in your log the macro variable "&prog3." is the one getting resolved instead of &prog1. and &prog2.

Try adding this to your code which prints all the user macro variables to the log.

```
%put _user_;
```